# SQL - Split container row conditionally

Tags: sql, oracle

In the process of migrating containers, if we have two tables;

1. `TABLE_MAPPING (old_value, new_value)`
2. `TABLE_USING (value, data...)`

`TABLE_USING` is referencing (FK) a container in a irrelevant table.
`TABLE_MAPPING` is temporarily used for a migration, the goal is to move contents from deprecated to new containers.

The problem here is that sometimes the container is not only replaced, but split into multiple new containers, for example `TABLE_MAPPING` could contain:

| OLD_VALUE | NEW VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 20 |

And the query would result in an "update" of one row with value '1' to two rows with values '10' and '11'.

Is there a plain SQL way to do that? Or should I use PL/SQL?

EDIT: as requested, here is an example of before/after using the `TABLE_MAPPING` above

**Before:**

| VALUE | IRRELEVANT_COLUMNS ... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |

**After:**

| VALUE | IRRELEVANT_COLUMNS ... |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | ... |
| 12 | ... |
| 20 | ... |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I formatted an example in the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two steps. Below I first insert all new rows, then I delete all old rows.

```
-- insert rows with new values
insert into table_using (value, data ...)
select m.new_value, u.data ...
from table_using u
join table_mapping m on m.old_value = u.value;

-- delete rows with old values
delete from table_using where value in (select old_value from table_mapping);

-- commit the transaction
commit;
```